# External URL id as Rails id Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, model-view-controller, routes

I haven't really got into routing with any framework and Routing is already complicated as it is. I need some help with it.

Im grabbing some data from an iTunes json file. I have all the top songs listed in my view. What I want to do is set up a route, when the user clicks one of the top songs, it takes them to the show_song page (and not get redirected to itunes song page). BUT I want to use the ID from the JSON file. In the show page, I want to use it like:

```
@song.title
@song.price
@song.image
etc.
```

how can I set the Song id to the iTunes json id??

Heres what I have in my index:

```
url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=25/json'
@resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
@data = JSON.parse(@resp.body)['feed']
```

I want to do a link_to the show page and show that songs info.

```
=link_to image_tag entry['im:image'][2], (grab the id from here)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do. It's OK to retrieve all the top song with the URL you provide. The tricky part was to know how render **only one song**.

After some search I found that Itunes provides a kind of API which is [available here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). As you can see, you can retrieve any content with its ID with a URL like `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=XXXXX`.

So the trick is to retrieve the ID of each entries from your first call and use it as a parameter (I did not do security tests on my example).

Create two statics views in a pages controller (for example) called `home` & `song`.

In your config/routes.rb you will have :

```
match  '/song/:id' => 'pages#song', via: [:get], as: :song
root 'pages#home'
```

My controller looks like this :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=25/json'
    @resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    @data = JSON.parse(@resp.body)['feed']
  end

  def song
    url = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=#{params[:id]}"
    @resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    @song = JSON.parse(@resp.body)['results'][0]
  end
end
```

My views for each action looks like this :

```
# Pages#home
<% @data['entry'].each do |song| %>
    First image : <%= song['im:image'][0]['label'] %>
    <br />
    Name : <%= song['im:collection']['im:name']['label'] %>
    <br />
    Link : <%= song['im:collection']['link']['attributes']['href'] %>
    <br />
    Price : <%= song['im:price']['label'] %>
    <br />
    ID : <%= song['id']['attributes']['im:id'] %>
    <br />
    <%= link_to "This song", song_path(song['id']['attributes']['im:id']) %>
    <hr>
<% end %>

# Pages#song
First image : <%= @song['artworkUrl100'] %>
<br />
Name : <%= @song['trackName'] %>
<br />
Link : <%= @song['trackViewUrl'] %>
<br />
Price : <%= @song['trackPrice'] %>
```

This is just a working example, you might clean up the code a little bit and add some security check on it.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked like a charm. But can you please explain to me what 'match' does for the route? Maybe I can get a little more of an understanding of whats going on behind the scenes. aha